# Getting handles to the credentials of a domain user from a process launched by a local user on Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, kerberos, sspi, credential-manager

**Background:**

- Computer `mycomputer` is running Windows 10 and is joined to domain `mydomain.com`.
- A user is logged with local account `mycomputer\localuser` on `mycomputer`.
- The user also knows the password of domain account `mydomain\domainuser`.
- The service principal name `myprotocol/domainuser` is registered in Active Directory and maps to domain account `mydomain\domainuser`.
- Local user `mycomputer\localuser` is not allowed to start a process as `mydomain\domainuser`.

The user wants to launch a server process under the local account which would then use the domain account to authenticate incoming connections with Kerberos.

I want to write the code of that server.

**Client code:**

The client code is straightforward and consist of a call to `AcquireCredentialsHandle` followed by a call to `InitializeSecurityContext`:

```
AcquireCredentialsHandle(
    nullptr,
    "Kerberos",
    SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    &credentials,
    &lifetime);
InitializeSecurityContext(
    &credentials,
    nullptr,
    "myprotocol/myport",
    ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY,
    0,
    SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP,
    nullptr,
    0,
    &securityContext,
    &outBufferArray,
    &contextAttributes,
    &lifetime);
```

Note the simplified usage of strings in the code snippets. The reality which have to deal with `wchar_t` and `const` correctness is somewhat uglier.

Also note that this code works when launched by a local user if appropriate credentials are stored in Control Panel's Credential Manager - i.e. with hostname `domainuser` (sic.)

**Server code:**

I already have a code which works when the process is launched by `mydomain\domainuser`:

```
AcquireCredentialsHandle(
    nullptr,
    "Kerberos",
    SECPKG_CRED_INBOUND,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    &credentials,
    &lifetime);
AcceptSecurityContext(
    &credentials,
    nullptr,
    &inBufferArray,
    attribs,
    SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP,
    &securityContext,
    nullptr,
    &attribs,
    &lifetime);
```

But when the server is launched by `mycomputer\localuser`, the call to `AcquireCredentialsHandle` fails with code `SEC_E_NO_CREDENTIALS`.

- I tried modifying the first argument of that call to `"myprotocol/domainuser"`, `"domainuser"`, `"mydomain\domainuser"` or even `"domainuser@mydomain.com"`.
- I tried adding the required credentials in Control Panel's Credential Manager using hostname `mycomputer` and even `domainuser`.

**What can I do to acquire the credential handle of `mydomain\domainuser` in a process launched by `mycomputer\localuser` ?**

Compiling code snippet:

```
#include <string>

#define NOMINMAX
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <sspi.h>//Requires linking on Secur32.lib

int main(){
    CredHandle credentials;
    TimeStamp lifetime;
    std::string package="Kerberos";
    std::string principal="myprotocol/domainuser";
    auto res=AcquireCredentialsHandle(
        principal.data(),
        package.data(),
        SECPKG_CRED_INBOUND,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &credentials,
        &lifetime);
    if(res==SEC_E_OK){
        std::printf("Success\n");
        FreeCredentialsHandle(&credentials);
        return 0;}
    else{
        std::printf("Failure\n");
        return res;}}
```

Comment: How are you setting credentials? That is almost always going to be the cause of SEC_E_NO_CREDENTIALS. It's also a bit strange that ACH is returning that. Usually it's ASC or ISC that returns it, since ACH doesn't do a lot under the covers.

Comment: @Steve I am not sure I understand your question. The user logs into Windows using his local account and then he runs the server code which executes the code snippet above. `AcquireCredentialsHandle` is supposed to initialize `credentials` but it fails because of `SECPKG_CRED_INBOUND`. On the client side, the same call with `SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND` works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, was doing this from memory and misremembered the parameters. You're passing null authdata (param 5) on the outbound ACH call, so it has to rely on the default local creds. However, local user credentials don't support SSO in this way because it has no knowledge of what realm you're in.

Comment: Check [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/obtaining-alternate-digest-credentials) to obtain credentials for a specific user account.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT It works. Please write an answer with the link. I will upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain credentials other than those associated with the current logon session, populate a [`SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/ns-sspi-sec_winnt_auth_identity_a) structure with information for the alternate security principal. Pass the structure to the `AcquireCredentialsHandle` function using the `pAuthData` parameter.

And [this micrsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/obtaining-alternate-digest-credentials) demonstrates a client-side call to obtain Digest credentials for a specific user account:

```
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef UNICODE
  ClientAuthID.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;
#else
  ClientAuthID.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_ANSI;
#endif

void main()
{
    SECURITY_STATUS SecStatus; 
    TimeStamp tsLifetime; 
    CredHandle hCred;
    SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY ClientAuthID;
    LPTSTR UserName = TEXT("ASecurityPrinciple");
    LPTSTR DomainName = TEXT("AnAuthenticatingDomain");

    // Initialize the memory.
    ZeroMemory( &ClientAuthID, sizeof(ClientAuthID) );

    // Specify string format for the ClientAuthID structure.


    // Specify an alternate user, domain and password.
      ClientAuthID.User = (unsigned char *) UserName;
      ClientAuthID.UserLength = _tcslen(UserName);

      ClientAuthID.Domain = (unsigned char *) DomainName;
      ClientAuthID.DomainLength = _tcslen(DomainName);

    // Password is an application-defined LPTSTR variable
    // containing the user password.
      ClientAuthID.Password = Password;
      ClientAuthID.PasswordLength = _tcslen(Password);

    // Get the client side credential handle.
    SecStatus = AcquireCredentialsHandle (
      NULL,                  // Default principal.
      WDIGEST_SP_NAME,       // The Digest SSP. 
      SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND,  // Client will use the credentials.
      NULL,                  // Do not specify LOGON id.
      &ClientAuthID,         // User information.
      NULL,                  // Not used with Digest SSP.
      NULL,                  // Not used with Digest SSP.
      &hCred,                // Receives the credential handle.
      &tsLifetime            // Receives the credential time limit.
    );
}
```